# Pass in ant properties to WLST task

Tags: ant, jython, wlst

I am invoking the WLST Task through Ant and I want to pass in properties defined in Ant's context either through importing property files inside ant, inaddition to ant startup arguments. (ie the properties are available in ant via property expansion)

The only way I can see to do this is to use the foreach/inheritall functionality of antcontrib. I however do not require any iterations.

Is there a solution without having to use antcontrib and a iteration loop of 1?

I want to reference the properties in the WLST script for example as
    print "ant property is",antproperty

Comment: Can you post some code? I use WSLD in Ant, and I can't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Solved

I was trying to initialise variables incorrectly.

The way to do this ie set a jython variable from an ant variable in WLST task is to use the sys.argv array.

This can either be done in the jython file itself or in the embedded script element in the WLST task.